# Replacing strings in a list with a number

Tags: python

So for the second part of my python project we have to identify individual words in a sentence, store them in a list and replace each word with the position of the word in the list. Here is what I have so far:

```
s = 'I am having a very nice day.'
split = s.split()
print(split)
len(s.split())
```

Comment: Looks good so far. What is your expected output?

Comment: What do you think the output should be for your example sentence?

Comment: So instead of the output being [I, AM, HAVING] it would be [0, 1, 2]

Comment: You should use regular expressions for this. Or just get the position of each space...

Comment: `list(range(len(s.split()))` (`list(...)` is not necessary in Python 2.x)

Comment: So you need to make a list of 0..N-1 where N is the number of words in the original string?

Comment: Please update the question to show this new information.

Comment: What about repeated words?  "the cat in the hat" should become what?

Comment: ['THE','CAT','IN','THE','HAT'] should become [0,1,2,3]

Comment: Please update the question to show this new information

Comment: So you actually *don't* want to replace each word with the position of the word in the list, because "the cat in the hat" has five words but [0,1,2,3] only has four elements.

Answer (score 3):

Is that is what you want?

```
s = 'I am having a very nice day.'
words = s.split()
res = list(range(len(words)))

print(res)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Then you may [accept this answer](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png)

Comment: Does not work with duplicate words

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
s = 'I am having a very nice day.'
sp_s = s.split()
l = [sp_s.index(x) for x in sp_s]
```

The output in `l` is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I strictly considered the fact of 'replace each word with the position'. A range() doesn't replace, it just fills a list from x to y.

Comment: I somehow don't think this answer should have been down voted.

Answer (score 2):

First solution:

```
>>> map(lambda x: s.split().index(x), s.split())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Second solution:

```
>>> range(len(s.split()))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: With repeated words you would get different results as `index` would only find the first instance of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the range of the length of the `split` list. This will give you all the numbers up the the length.

```
s = 'I am having a very nice day.'
print(range(len(s.split())))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "I am having a very nice day."

words = list(set(re.findall(r'\w+', s)))
print words

s2 = re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m: str(words.index(m.group(0))), s)
print s2
```

outputs:

```
['a', 'I', 'am', 'day', 'very', 'having', 'nice']
1 2 5 0 4 6 3.
```

Comment: using `set()` messed with the ordering

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: In the comments... "[I, AM, HAVING] would be [0, 1, 2]"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new index for duplicate words:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> for word in "the cat in the hat".split():
>>>     if word not in d:
>>>         d[word] = len(d)
>>> [word[0] for word in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])]
['the', 'cat', 'in', 'hat']
>>>> [d[word] for word in "the cat in the hat".split()]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that more closely matches your original attempt. This should work with duplicates and uses the original array as well.

```
s = 'I am having a very nice day.'
split = s.split()
print(split)
length = len(split)
index = length - 1
while (index >= 0):
    split[index] = index;
    index = index - 1;
print(split)
```